# Don't print blank lines when data fields are empty

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I am using WordPress' WooCommerce theme. The result leaves a empty space if a form field is left blank. I *don't* want to print blank lines when the input data fields of a form are empty. So if QC and QO in the form are left blank, it prints a blank space in the output form. Check the image below.

```
$res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QA:</u></span>';

if( ! empty( $feild1 ) )
    $res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild1 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild2 ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QC:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild2 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild3 ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QO:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild3 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild4 ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QP:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild4 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

# Where feild xxx=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_input_feild xxx', TRUE);
```

Is it better to delete the meta value from the post if left blank, as the database can be full of blank meta data? Should we delete meta_value with an empty or null value. Will it affect anything?

[image: Vlank space created]

Comment: *[field](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/field#Noun)* is misspelt as *feild*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```php
$res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QA:</u></span>';

if( ! empty( stripslashes($feild1) ) )
    $res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild1 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( stripslashes($feild2) ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QC:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild2 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( stripslashes($feild3) ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QO:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild3 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( stripslashes($feild4) ) )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QP:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">' . $feild4 . '</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';
```

Try this CSS:

```css
.acc-t ul {
    margin-bottom:0px !important;
    margin-top:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: all feilds still have blank output.any other solution

Comment: use var_dump to print `$feild2` value ans share me here

Comment: C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\custom\custom.php:1127:string '' (length=0) ......its a code which i uploaded in form of plugin by name custom

Comment: C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\custom\custom.php:1123:string 'test' (length=4)   this is for $feild1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well. Give it a try to see if it works...

```
$res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QA:</u></span>';

if( ! empty( $feild1 ) && strlen($feild1) > 0  )
    $res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">'.$feild1.'</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild2 ) && strlen($feild2) > 0 )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QC:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">'.$feild2.'</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild3 ) && strlen($feild3) > 0 )
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QO:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">'.$feild3.'</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';

if( ! empty( $feild4 ) && strlen($feild4) > 0)
    $res .= '<li class="acc-t"><span id="si"><u>QP:</u></span>';
$res .= '<span id="hh" ><div class="acc-cont">'.$feild4.'</div></span>';
$res .= '</li>';
```

Comment: do an echo inside the if condition where it the black space is coming.... let me know the output

Comment: {
    echo "Have a good day!";
}else {
    echo 'good day"';
}   no error

Comment: Not clear. please echo the respective field value inside if for which the field value expected to be empty

Comment: didn't get you ,it is still showing blank.so....if  ! empty then results are displayed and if empty results are not displayed which i am expecting but it displays blank  space of field 2 n 3

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53426429/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).